# CoreLocation does not seem to be recognized

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I recently installed cocoa pods into xcode and started my project in the proper file. Im learning swift on udemy and part of our assignment is to create a weather app using the library CoreLocation. the issue is, xcode doesn't seem to recognize that library. When I hold command and click on find definition, a question mark pops up. In the udemy videos im watching, My instructor is easily able to read the definition of the library. Could this be an issue with CocoaPods? Im sure I am writing it correctly because i am following the videos word for word.

```
import UIKit

import Corelocation


class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //Constants
    let WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    let APP_ID = "e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713"


    //TODO: Declare instance variables here
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()



    //Pre-linked IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.Delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation is an Apple Framework so ensure you have:

```
import CoreLocation
```

above the class definition where you wish to use parts of this framework.

Hope that helps.